# Constraint Mismatch Error when Matching on Data Type

Tags: f#, dictionary, types, match

I am trying to process the contents of a dictionary based on the type of contained element (String, Int, Datetime etc). The following is a small test snippet which loads some test data and then extracts by type.

However I get the following constraint mismatch error which I don't understand - any ideas?

**Error Info**:

> unmapdict.fsx(29,23): error FS0193: Type constraint mismatch. 
>   
> The type 'String' is not compatible with the type 'Type'

```
open System
open System.Collections.Generic

// Type for dict entries
type dStruct =  {
   ftype: Type; 
   fvalue:obj;
}

let main() =
    printfn "\n>>>>>> Extract Dictionary Elements  <<<<< \n" 
    let ddict = new Dictionary<string, dStruct>()
    let str = "String Data"
    let rstring =  { ftype=str.GetType(); fvalue=str ;}
    ddict.Add("String", rstring)
    let intn = 999
    let rint32 =  { ftype=intn.GetType(); fvalue=intn ;}
    ddict.Add("Int32", rint32)

    let rdatetime =  {ftype=System.DateTime.Now.GetType(); fvalue=System.DateTime.Now}
    ddict.Add("DateTime", rdatetime)

    // Extract dict value elements; emumerate data types
    ddict
        |> Seq.map ( fun (KeyValue(k,v)) -> v)
        |> Seq.iter (fun v ->  
                    // Error occurs here >>
                    match v.ftype with 
                    | :?System.String -> printfn "String Found ";
                    | :?System.Int32 -> printfn "Integer Found ";
                    | :?System.DateTime -> printfn "DateTime Found ";
                    |_ -> printfn "Unmatched Element"
                    // printfn "Dict: ftype: %A; fvalue: %A" v.ftype v.fvalue
                    )

    printfn "\n>>>>>> F# Done  <<<<< \n" 

main()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since .NET objects carry their types with them, I don't see any point to the `dStruct` type (which is misleadingly named anyway, since it's not a struct).  On a related note, your type test patterns (`:? string`, etc.) don't work because you're testing an instance of class `Type` against them, when you should be testing the instance that you actually care about.  That is:

```
let main() =
    printfn "\n>>>>>> Extract Dictionary Elements  <<<<< \n" 
    let ddict = new Dictionary<string, obj>()
    let str = "String Data"
    ddict.Add("String", str)
    let intn = 999
    ddict.Add("Int32", intn)

    ddict.Add("DateTime", System.DateTime.Now)

    // Extract dict value elements; emumerate data types
    ddict
        |> Seq.map ( fun (KeyValue(k,v)) -> v)
        |> Seq.iter (fun v ->  
                    match v with 
                    | :?System.String as s -> printfn "String Found: %s" s;
                    | :?System.Int32 as i -> printfn "Integer Found: %i" i;
                    | :?System.DateTime as dt -> printfn "DateTime Found: %A" dt;
                    |_ -> printfn "Unmatched Element"
                    )

    printfn "\n>>>>>> F# Done  <<<<< \n" 

main()
```

Comment: Good catch on the redundancy here - as you pointed out all I need her (Type info etc) is available from the net objects themselves. Thx

Answer (score 2):

A .NET `Type` as returned by `GetType` is not the same as a class. Instead, it is an instance of class `Type`. Also, `Type` cannot be used in pattern matching (unless we define special active patterns), but we can compare for equality.

If you change your code like this, it will work:

```
               if v.ftype  = typeof<String> then printfn "String Found "
               elif v.ftype = typeof<System.Int32> then printfn "Integer Found "
               elif v.ftype = typeof<System.DateTime> then printfn "DateTime Found "
               else printfn "Unmatched Element"
```